# Python code using sockets works in command line but not in script

Tags: python, sockets, command-line

I have the following code that attempts to turn on a lamp via ethernet commands

```
##################
% LampOn.py
import sys, socket
HOST='10.0.0.10'
PORT=1000
print 'Turning on Illuminator...'
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('GSS=1\r')
s.close()
print 'Illuminator On ...'
##################
```

When I type each line of the script, individually, in the Python command window, the lamp turns on. However, when I run this script through the Windows command prompt using

```
>>python LampOn.py
```

The lamp does not turn on. But, the PRINT messages at the beginning and end of the code get displayed, so I know that the script itself is being executed (no errors are displayed). Can anyone offer suggestions as to what I am doing wrong (I'm new to both Python and using sockets)?

BTW - I'm using Python 2.7.8 on a Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit machine

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - the first line actually reads #LampOn.py

Comment: You can edit your own post using the edit button

Comment: I assume the lamp never sends any confirmation messages back or anything? Just a one-way street?

Comment: One of the issues with your current code, from my perspective, is that it doesn't confirm that the socket connection was successful. Right now you code will just push on through unless something truly odd happens. An easy way to catch any such problems at this point would be to use socket.connect_ex(address) instead of plain socket. The docs are pretty clear on how it works: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect_ex Additionally I would double check that nothing odd is happening with your HOST or PORT values.

Comment: One of my first suggestions to help rule out interpreter weirdness would be to wrap your script's main activities in a `main` method and call it explicitly from the main thread. See the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line and the line after it (note that the `sys.exit` command is not strictly necessary): http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829